# @Autowired failed under @SpringBootTest

Tags: spring-boot, autowired, spring-boot-test

I am learning how to run @SpringBootTest the "right way", but is encountering a problem with autowiring in my test classes (in "src/test/java" directory):

I have a class Graphs which is annotated by @Component in a package under "src/main/java":

```
@Component
public class Graphs {
  ....
}
```

Then, I created test classes under "src/test/java". One of them is:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class GraphsTest {   
   @Test
   public void testRun () {
      Graphs graph = new Graphs(); // Using new to create an object
      if (graph==null) {
        System.out.println("It's null");
      } else {
        System.out.println("It's not null");
      }         
   }
...
```

When I test run "testRun" method, it produced "It's not null" as expected.

After unit tests, i wanted to inject a "graph" as Graphs class was annotated by @Component thus a bean should be available for autowiring:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class GraphTest {
   @Autowired
   private Graphs graph;    // auto inject a bean graph 

   @Test
   public void testRun () {
     if (graph==null) {
        System.out.println("it's null");
     } else {
        System.out.println("it's not null");
     }
   }
 ....
```

Now with autowiring, "testRun" always produced: "it's null" even when I attempted the following, ("xxxxxx" is the full name of the package which contains Graphs.java file):

1. adding @Import(xxxxxx/Graphs.class)
2. adding @ComponentScan("xxxxxxx")
3. copying the Graphs.java file into the test package
4. Adding a @Bean into TestConfiguration.java in the test package.

   `@Bean
    public Graphs graph () {
       return new Graphs();
    }`

I started to suspect that I have fundamentally misunderstood/missed something about setting up a Spring Boot test environment: isn't it @SpringBootTest all I need to get started?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` above `GraphTest`.

`SpringRunner` is the alias for `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` which is responsible, among other things, for load `TestContextManager` (see [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.html)). Without it, your application context wouldn't be loaded for tests.

Comment: Like to clarify: did you mean "Without it, your application context would NOT be loaded for tests"?

Comment: This brought to my other headache: when I use @RunWith(SpringRunner.class), I got "InitializationError". I posted this problem separately just now.